# Suppress Mail.app Welcome Dialog Post Applescript Setup

Tags: macos, applescript

I'm attempting to configure the OSX Mail application via AppleScript. Upon running the AppleScript configuration, the "Welcome to Mail" dialog appears, when no accounts are setup. But I'm trying to setup the account via AppleScript...

Is it possible to configure the Mail application, and suppress the Welcome to Mail dialog?

I believe the problem is centered around this command:

```
tell application "Mail"
activate
```

This is essentially launching the application and then my script proceeds to configure. If you cancel out of the "Welcome to Mail" dialog, the Mail application quits. If you already have an account setup, the AppleSript command to setup an account works just fine.

Does anyone know if there is a way to suppress this window?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to suppress it from popping up, but you could hide it using this code:

```
tell application "System Events" to set visible of process "Mail" to false
```

Of course, later on you could show it to the user again, using
    tell application "System Events" to set visible of process "Mail" to true